# A bizarre glitch when animating a flex box-based progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I am trying to learn flexbox by implementing a progress bar.
Everything works fine until i try to animate the thing with jquery...

[image]

`Animate` does not seem to work well for the right half after the width is set to at least 75%.

Also it's like the green bar is set to a very big width since it actually takes about a second to come back from 100%+.

I'm not sure if the cause is me not knowing flexbox very well or jQuery freaking out for some reason...

Is this a known issue? Did I do something wrong? Here is my page's code.

This is my code:

```css
button {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
}

.b9k-progress {
  border: solid black 2px;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.b9k-left,
.b9k-right {
  height: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.b9k-left {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 1;
}

.b9k-right {
  background: orangered;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 80%;margin: 20px 10% ;">
  <button onclick='$("#the-progress-bar>.b9k-left").animate({"width": "0"},2000);'>ZERO</button>
  <button onclick='$("#the-progress-bar>.b9k-left").animate({"width": "20%"},2000);'>25%
    </button>
  <button onclick='$("#the-progress-bar>.b9k-left").animate({"width": "50%"},2000);'>50%
    </button>
  <button onclick='$("#the-progress-bar>.b9k-left").animate({"width": "75%"},2000);'>75%
    </button>
  <button onclick='$("#the-progress-bar>.b9k-left").animate({"width": "100%"},2000);'>100%
    </button>
</div>


<div id="the-progress-bar" class="b9k-progress">
  <div class="b9k-left"></div>
  <div class="b9k-right"></div>
</div>
```

Is this a known issue? did I do something wrong?

Comment: Why use jQuery animate (and inline JS), when you can easily use CSS transitions?

Comment: ^ and why two elements when you can only use one?

Comment: @Terry I did not dabble in CSS transitions yet :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I was planning to add some conent inside the divs, like a percentage text or something like that, so I wanted to keep the divs 'inhabitable'

Comment: still the right div is useless. you can remove it and have a background color on the main div that will be covered by the left element

Comment: I copied your snippet and changed the jQuery version to 3.3.1, and it works as expected. I would update jQuery if you are intent on using it

Comment: I think it's possible you've uncovered a bug in that version of jQuery animate; for what it's worth while your code could be simplified, there's nothing obviously wrong in it. (If you watch in the dev tools you an see that when it animates from a high value to a low value it's animating a px instead of % value, which comes out wrong in flexbox.)

Comment: (And yes, it looks like jQuery 3.3.1 animates a % value in both directions, so as KevBot points out doesn't have this problem.)

Comment: @ DanielBeck and @KevinBot I didn't expect that... :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because when you are using CSS flexbox *in conjunction* with percentage based widths, you are forcing the browser to make multiple passes when trying to determine the final width of the element. This causes the bar to initially overshoot its width to >100%, before jQuery properly animates it to the target value.

## Solution 1: Use CSS transitions

You don't even need to use jQuery's animate function at all. It can be cumbersome to work with and has catch-alls that people don't know (such as using `.stop(true, true)` to clear the queue, which you are not using). What you're trying to achieve can be done *purely using CSS transitions alone*:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.button').on('click', function() {
    $('#the-progress-bar > .b9k-left').width($(this).data('target-width'));
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
}

.b9k-progress {
  border: solid black 2px;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.b9k-left,
.b9k-right {
  height: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  
  /* Enable transition of width */
  transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
}

.b9k-left {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 1;
  
  /* Give the width a starting value */
  width: 0;
}

.b9k-right {
  background: orangered;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 80%;margin: 20px 10% ;">
  <button class="button" data-target-width="0">ZERO</button>
  <button class="button" data-target-width="25%">25%
    </button>
  <button class="button" data-target-width="50%">50%
    </button>
  <button class="button" data-target-width="75%">75%
    </button>
  <button class="button" data-target-width="100%">100%
    </button>
</div>


<div id="the-progress-bar" class="b9k-progress">
  <div class="b9k-left"></div>
  <div class="b9k-right"></div>
</div>
```

## Solution 2: Don't use flexbox

A way around this is to actually just remove the use of CSS flexbox, and instead assign the orange background to the parent element instead:

```css
button {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
}

.b9k-progress {
  background-color: orangered;
  border: solid black 2px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px white;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.b9k-left {
  height: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.b9k-left {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 80%;margin: 20px 10% ;">
  <button onclick='$("#the-progress-bar>.b9k-left").animate({"width": "0"},2000);'>ZERO</button>
  <button onclick='$("#the-progress-bar>.b9k-left").animate({"width": "20%"},2000);'>25%
    </button>
  <button onclick='$("#the-progress-bar>.b9k-left").animate({"width": "50%"},2000);'>50%
    </button>
  <button onclick='$("#the-progress-bar>.b9k-left").animate({"width": "75%"},2000);'>75%
    </button>
  <button onclick='$("#the-progress-bar>.b9k-left").animate({"width": "100%"},2000);'>100%
    </button>
</div>


<div id="the-progress-bar" class="b9k-progress">
  <div class="b9k-left"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's some valuable insight. Actually I expected even basic CSS transitions to be very complex. Your answer is very explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this with CSS animations, by just switching the classes on the element:

```
<div id="the-progress-bar" class="b9k-progress">
    <div class="the-progress-bar-progress"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
.the-progress-bar {
    background-color: orangered;
}

.the-progress-bar-progress { 
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; height: 100%; 
    background-color: green;
    transition: transform 2s;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.the-progress-bar-progress--25perc  { transform: scaleX(.25); }
.the-progress-bar-progress--50perc  { transform: scaleX(.5);  }
.the-progress-bar-progress--75perc  { transform: scaleX(.75); }
.the-progress-bar-progress--100perc { transform: scaleX(1);   }
```

And you can use this example function to simply change the class applied to the progress:

```
function changeProgress(e) {
    var progressBar = document.getElementById('the-progress-bar');
    progressBar.classList = 'b9k-progress';

    var targetClass = e.target.getAttribute('data-progressClass');
    if(targetClass && targetClass != '') { 
        progressBar.classList.add(targetClass);
    };
};
```

---

```
<button onclick='changeProgres();' data-progressClass="">ZERO</button>
<button onclick='changeProgres();' data-progressClass="the-progress-bar-progress--25perc">25%</button>
<button onclick='changeProgres();' data-progressClass="the-progress-bar-progress--50perc">50%</button>
```

or

```
function changeProgress(progressClass__string) {
    var targetClass = progressClass__string || '';
    document.getElementById('the-progress-bar').classList = 'b9k-progress ' + progressClass__string;
};
```

---

```
<button onclick="changeProgres();">ZERO</button>
<button onclick="changeProgres('the-progress-bar-progress--25perc');">25%</button>
<button onclick="changeProgres('the-progress-bar-progress--50perc');">50%</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is an entirely different take on my initial idea. I appreciate it!

Comment: Glad it helped. Best of luck! :)